# Spark Scala GraphX: Shortest path between two vertices

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a directed graph G in Spark GraphX (Scala). I would like to find the number of edges that should be crossed starting from a known vertex `v1` to arrive in another vertex `v2`. In other words, I need the shortest path from the vertex `v1` to the vertex `v2` calculated in number of edges (not using the edges' weights).

I was looking at the [GraphX documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#graph-operators), but I wasn't able to find a method to do it. This is also needed in order to compute the depth of the graph if it has a tree structure. Is their an easy way to do this?

Comment: You mean the number of edges between v1 and v2 or the number of possible paths from v1 to v2, passing by 0 or more additional vertices?

Comment: Hey, I meant number of edges between v1 and v2 from its shortest path. Updated to make more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. You want to find the shortest path between v1 and v2? When you say edges between v1 and v2, I think about the edges that directly connect v1 and v2, and not the shortest path.

Comment: What I mean is: In my graph G, For vectors v1 and v2, I want to find the minimum number of edges i have to cross to connect v1 and v2. Does that make more sense? G is a directed graph.

Comment: Ok, so you want to solve the [Shortest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)? I will make a suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Yes that sounds right. Assuming the edge weights are 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the shortest path between vertices using Spark GraphX, there is the [ShortestPaths](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths$) object, which is member of the [org.apache.spark.graphx.lib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.package).

Assuming you have a GraphX graph in `g` and you want to find the shortest path between the vertices with ids `v1` and `v2`, you can do the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths

val result = ShortestPaths.run(g, Seq(v2))

val shortestPath = result               // result is a graph
  .vertices                             // we get the vertices RDD
  .filter({case(vId, _) => vId == v1})  // we filter to get only the shortest path from v1
  .first                                // there's only one value
  ._2                                   // the result is a tuple (v1, Map)
  .get(v2)                              // we get its shortest path to v2 as an Option object
```

The ShortestPaths GraphX algorithm returns a graph where the vertices RDD contains tuples in the format `(vertexId, Map(target -> shortestPath)`. This graph will contain all vertices of the original graph, and their shortest paths to all target vertices passed in the `Seq` argument of the algorithm.

In your case, you want the shortest path between two specific vertices, so in the code above I show how to call the algorithm with only one target (`v2`), and then I filter the result to get only the shortest path starting from the desired vertex (`v1`).

Comment: Hey. This worked great for individual pairs, but i'm getting a null pointer error when doing it for a list of pairs. I documented above. Do you happen to know what might be causing it?

Comment: @mt88 maybe the object G has some problem? Have you tried printing some of G elements?

Comment: Don't want to bury this question in my particular example, so I deleted my update. I posted a new question and reproducible example with that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175738/spark-scala-graphx-calling-shortest-path-within-a-map-function

Comment: Daniel, am I correct in saying this only works for unweighted graphs? As in, all weights are taken as 1.

Comment: It's worth nothing that this gives the *length* of the shortest path, not the actual path.

Comment: @MichaelMior Maybe the question text is ambiguous, but the OP wanted the "minimum number of edges between two vertices", so this answer is worth something, at least for him.

Comment: For sure :) I just thought I would point that out in case someone came here looking for the path and got confused.